# How to use Rx.NET in a pipeline mixing network and file system IO?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have the following requirement:

1. Collect certain information from multiple remote sites.
2. Serialize the information to disk.
3. Contact the same sites and acknowledge the data was collected successfully.

This is a very simplified flow, the real flow must also deal with faults and has other aspects, which I think are irrelevant to my question or so it seems for the moment.

Anyway, here is how I implement the described flow:

```
var data = await GetSitesSource()
    .Select(site => Observable
        .FromAsync(() => GetInformationFromSiteAsync(site))
        .Select(site.MakeKeyValuePair))
    .Merge(maxConcurrentSiteRequests)
    .ToList();

if (data.Count > 0)
{
    var filePath = GetFilePath();
    using (var w = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        await w.WriteAsync(YieldLines(data));
    }
    var tsUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
    await data.ToObservable()
        .Select(o => Observable.FromAsync(() => AckInformationFromSiteAsync(o.Key, tsUTC, o.Value.InformationId)))
        .Merge(maxConcurrentSiteRequests);
}
```

Where:

- `MakeKeyValuePair` is an extension method that returns a `KeyValuePair<K,V>` instance
- `YieldLines` transforms `data` into an `IEnumerable<string>`
- `WriteAsync` is a fictional extension method writing a series of strings to its `StreamWriter`

It does not seem a good implementation, because I do not leverage the fact that I could have started writing out the records as they come out of the first `Merge` operator.

I could use `SelectMany` + `Merge(1)` operator to asynchronously write out the chunks to the file (the order does not matter), but how do I make sure the respective `StreamWriter` is initialized only when needed and is properly disposed of? Because if there is no data, I do not even want to  initialize the `StreamWriter`.

My question - how can this code be rewritten, so that the Observable pipeline is not interrupted in the middle to write out the file? It should includes all the three phases:

1. Get the data from multiple sites
2. Write the data in chunks one by one, the order does not matter
3. Acknowledge the data once all the data is written

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but none of your code precludes joining it together. So you could do something like this:

```
//The ToObservable extension for Task is only available through
using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;

GetSitesSource()
    .Select(site => Observable
        .FromAsync(() => GetInformationFromSiteAsync(site))
        .Select(site.MakeKeyValuePair))
    .Merge(maxConcurrentSiteRequests)
    .ToList()
    //Only proceed if we received data
    .Where(data => data.Count > 0)
    .SelectMany(data =>
      //Gives the StreamWriter the same lifetime as this Observable once it subscribes
      Observable.Using(
        () => new StreamWriter(GetFilePath()), 
        (w) => w.WriteAsync(YieldLines(data)).ToObservable()),
      //We are interested in the original data value, not the write result
      (data, _) => data)
    //Attach a timestamp of when data passed through here
    .Timestamp()
    .SelectMany(o=> {
      var ts = o.Timestamp;
      var data= o.Value;
      //This is actually returning IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> but merge
      //will implicitly handle it.
      return data.Select(i => Observable.FromAsync(() => 
                               AckInformationFromSiteAsync(i.Key, ts,
                                                           i.Value.InformationId)))
                .Merge(maxConcurrentSiteRequests);
    })
    //Handle the return values, fatal errors and the completion of the stream.
    .Subscribe();
```

To more fully answer your question

The `Using` operator ties a resource which must implement `IDisposable` to the lifetime of the Observable. The first argument is a factory function that will get called once when the Observable is subscribed to.

Comment: Formally, yes you did it. However, this does not, and I quote from my own post, "leverage the fact that I could have started writing out the records as they come out of the first Merge operator". Hence this pipeline is as "bad" as me breaking the pipeline.